# AD + Postfix + Dovecot problems with query_filter

Tags: postfix, kerberos, dovecot

I set up a mail server AD + Postfix + Dovecot + Kerberos

This works fine for only one domain In the attribute mail=test@test.com, in otherMailbox=vasya@otherdoamin.com,petya@another.net

**Config files:**

Postfix ldap-users.cf

```
server_host = server
search_base = dc=cn,dc=energy
version = 3
bind = yes
bind_dn = ldapmail@cn.energy
bind_pw = passwd

query_filter = (&(objectCategory=person)(|(mail=%s)(otherMailbox=%s))(!(userAccountControl=514)))
result_attribute = mail otherMailbox
result_format = %d/%u
```

dovecot-ldap.conf

```
hosts = server:3268
debug_level = 2
dn = ldapmail
dnpass = passwd
tls = no
auth_bind = yes
auth_bind_userdn = cn.energy\%u
ldap_version = 3
base = dc=cn, dc=energy
deref = searching
scope = subtree
user_attrs = mail=user,uid=vmail, gid=vmail
user_filter = (&(objectclass=person)(|(sAMAccountName=%n)(otherMailbox=%n))(!(userAccountControl=514)))
default_pass_scheme = CRYPT
```

**postconf:**

attribute mail

```
postmap -q ross@test.com ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-users.cf
another.net/petya,otherdoamin.com/vasya,test@test.com/ross
```

attribute otherMailbox

```
postmap -q ross@otherdoamin.com ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-users.cf
another.net/petya,otherdoamin.com/vasya,test@test.com/ross
```

The filter searches and finds the correct.
Just does not work result_format ???

example:

```
another.net/petya,otherdoamin.com/vasya,test@test.com/ross
```

this name one directory ! hmmm dovecot dont find it

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please specify your question? What's your problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem that your postfix ldap query works but your dovecot ldap query doesn't?

Then you probably take a closer look at your mapping of the `user_attrs` in the dovecot-ldap.conf. You specifiy in the `user_attrs` *ldap-attribute* = *dovecot-attribute*. There might be something wrong here because dovecot doesn't know an attribute named vmail [1](http://wiki.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase#lookupdbs),[2](http://wiki.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/ExtraFields). See:

http://wiki.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase#lookupdbs and http://wiki.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/ExtraFields